# Aurelia Typescript and DI

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I running into an issue where I expect the object(Applicant in the example) reference to be the same, but not getting the expected behavior in this example, it be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

app.ts:

```
@inject(HttpClient, Applicant)
export class App {
    applicant: Applicant;
    http: HttpClient;
    router: Router;

    constructor(httpClient, applicant) {
        this.applicant = applicant;
        this.http = httpClient;
        this.applicant.firstName = "John";
    }
//router config code..
updateApplicant() {
    this.http.get("/fakeApplicant.json")
        .then(response => {
            this.applicant = response.content; //Sets first name to Mike
        });
}
```

start.ts

```
@inject(Applicant)
export class start {
    router: Router;
    applicant: Applicant;

    constructor(applicant : Applicant) {
        this.applicant = applicant;
    }
```

app.html

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="appHost">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <button click.delegate="updateApplicant()">Update First Name</button>

    <h3>App First Name: ${applicant.firstName}</h3>
</div>
```

start.html

```
<template>
<h1>Start</h1>

<h3>Start First Name: ${applicant.firstName}</h3>
</template>
```

---

Okay, so above should be pretty simple, I have the main app, the start.html is just a route that will get loaded on start in router-view.  As expected, both App and Start First Name binding initially shows up as John.  However, when I click updateApplicant delegate which executes the http get call, only the App First Name binding is updated to Mike, I'm expecting the Start view's applicant to be updated as well, since they should be referencing the same Applicant object, right? I'm fairly new to Aurelia, not sure if the way I'm doing DI to inject the Applicant to use in different views is the right way, I'm expecting the Applicant object to be a singleton and want to inject into different views in the application.  I initially thought it was a ts lexical scoping issue, but it would mean nothing should get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Behavior

No, you are not. Since JS variables are just references to objects in memory, your variable `applicant` is just a reference, and when you change it in function `updateApplican` you just change reference to **another** object in memory. That is mean that reference in `start` view is **still refering** to the old one.

### Solution

There is one trick. You can store your `Aplicant` in wrapper. It would be looks like below

```
 //make it also singleton
 class AplicantWrapper {
       aplicant: Aplicant;
 }
```

And then inject it to your views

```
@inject(HttpClient, ApplicantWrapper)
export class App {
applicantWraper: ApplicantWrapper;
http: HttpClient;
router: Router;

constructor(httpClient, applicant) {
    this.applicantWraper = applicant;
    this.http = httpClient;
    this.applicant.firstName = "John";
}
   //router config code..
 updateApplicant() {
      this.http.get("/fakeApplicant.json")
          .then(response => {
                this.applicantWrapper.applicant = response.content; //Sets first name to Mike
          });
  }
```

In this case both view would expect changes because it still refering to same wrapper object

Comment: This is correct, so I will not change it. I will say, since Applicant is its own class, the best practice here would be to have an Applicant.update method and leverage that instead.

Comment: I have no deals with aurelia, my answer based on understending how DI works at all

Comment: Thanks Oleg and Matthew! I should have realized it, great suggestions that solved the problem!